# Compiling OpenCV Android using Cygwin

Tags: opencv, makefile, cygwin

I have a little experience in Cygwin configuration. I have followed a written setup tutorial which I obtained from Stanford Univerity coursework; specifically Tutorial 2. Unfortunately, during the compilation at step number 3c, I encountered an error and I couldn't execute the make command.

**I am getting the following Error:**

```
cypat_000@Seattle ~/opencv/android/build
$ make

[100%] Generating android-opencv

Compile thumb  : png <= /home/cypat_000/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.c
/home/cypat_000/android-ndk-r4-crystax/build/core/build-binary.mk:169: recipe for target '/home/cypat_000/opencv/android/build/obj/local/armeabi/objs/png/png.o' failed

make[3]: *** [/home/cypat_000/opencv/android/build/obj/local/armeabi/objs/png/png.o] Error 127
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

CMakeFiles/ndk.dir/build.make:55: recipe for target 'android-opencv' failed
make[2]: *** [android-opencv] Error 2

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ndk.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ndk.dir/all] Error 2

Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: you want to write JNI program ??

Comment: Hi Navdeep, exactly, I am trying to develop an simple android application using OpenCV library.Do you have any idea about the above error?

Comment: seems like your lib *.o failed to generate

Comment: Which means during the compile thumb:png stage it didn't actually compile the png.c thus fail to generate png.o? Sorry, this is quite new to me.Appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Step 1: Add NDK path to your workspace. Also make sure you have c,c++ installed in your cygwin.
Step 2: Add JNI files: *.c and mk files to your project under jni directory. (I hope you know how to do this)
Step 3: Right click on project > Android Tools> Add Native Support to your project.
Step 4: Right click on project > Build > Build All
```

Let me know if need further info.

Comment: Thanks for you information. Just a little clarification, is it the above mentioned steps are the step to be done eclipse? My apology if I didn't mention clearly, I wish to do it in Cygwin terminal. I just curious pertaining the error occur at the make stage.

Comment: oh i forgot to mention, yeah with eclipse